# Идентификатор пакета содержит недопустимые символы. Примеры допустимых значений: 'MyPackage'", "'MyPackage.Sample'

Tags: visual-studio, build, nuget, build-error

При сборке возникает такая ошибка:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\*версия*\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5): error : Идентификатор пакета "*название проекта*" содержит недопустимые символы. Примеры допустимых значений: 'MyPackage'", "'MyPackage.Sample'"
При создания нового проекта и перемещения всего остального ошибка не возникает до тех пор, пока не будет перемещен файл проекта (.csproj), но изменение файла проекта не даёт никаких результатов. При этом, повторное нажатие кнопки "собрать" может не вызывать этой ошибки (даже если код не был изменен). Ошибка возникла примерно после переименования проекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго не мог разобраться с этой странной проблемой, но решение оказалось довольно тривиальным: необходимо пройти по пути C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\ *версия* \Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\ и удалить папку build. После этого, эта ошибка больше не появляется